# Resize Container to Image

Tags: html, css, size, position

I have an image container with height 100% and an image fitting the height (made with display:inline). What I wanna do now is making the container width shrink to fit the resized image.

The Problem: The container shrinks to the ORIGINAL Size of the image, not the resized version.

Comment: Please post some code, or even better, a demo (jsfiddle).

Comment: do you mean that you're resizing the image at runtime?

Comment: please show code through jsfiddle so that we can update to make it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Now the container behaves the way I want it. The pictures are resized dynamically according to the given height. The container resizes according to the width of all pictures. The only thing left is that in case that the user is changing the window size, the site has to be reloaded (Can be done with js). If someone has got a better solution, please let me know.

http://jsfiddle.net/EdgKr/9/

Answer (score 0):

you could add an "onLoad" action to the image, something like `onload="sizeCont();`

```
function sizeCont() {
  document.getElementById("containerID").style.width = 
    document.getElementById("imageID").style.width;
  }
```

Comment: I would prefer a pure CSS sollution.

Comment: not sure if that's going to happen since the image is being resized to fit, but why not just set the image to be the background of the container, and size it accordingly?

Comment: Because this is a blog with lots of different sized images.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `<img src.....` and set the `width: 100%`. Try that and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes. That works, but it doesnt solve my problem. Now I got my images positioned, but also a container that should fit to all the images and again is too large. (It is a sidescrolling gallery)

Comment: The green box has to be shorter

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand what you want. Can you show me an example on the web?

Comment: Yes, but its kind of a mess: http://www.bastards-design.de/wordpress/category/allgemein/portfolio/grafik/#alina

Comment: As you can see, the div called row is as large as the container that holds it. But everything should be the size of the two images plus a margin on the right.

Comment: And here is the fiddle again. I had a "," too much, sorry for that: http://jsfiddle.net/EdgKr/7/

Comment: If you want a side-scrolling gallery like the one in the link, do it like this: (Link incoming)